# How to generate path to imported file in React dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a problem with generated dynamic path to import file in React.
I used map() function for generated dynamic part of code, which is a sequence of the same few div elements with an audio element inside this div. This code looks like this:

```
    {soundsName.map((sound, i) => {
          return (
            <div
              className="drum-pad"
              onClick={this.soundPlay}
              title={"Sound " + sound}
              key={i}
            >
              <audio className="clip" id={sound}>
                <source src={`s${i}`} type="audio/mpeg"></source>
              </audio>
              {sound}
            </div>
          );
        })}
```

My problem is that the generated path in 'src' for 'source' element is wrong.
The path is only the name of imported file, like 's1', 's2', 's3' and so on.

Files are imported like this:

```
    import s0 from "./assets/sounds/s1.mp3";
    import s1 from "./assets/sounds/s2.mp3";
    import s2 from "./assets/sounds/s3.mp3";
    import s3 from "./assets/sounds/s4.mp3";
    import s4 from "./assets/sounds/s5.mp3";
    import s5 from "./assets/sounds/s6.mp3";
    import s6 from "./assets/sounds/s7.mp3";
    import s7 from "./assets/sounds/s8.mp3";
    import s8 from "./assets/sounds/s9.mp3";
```

I really don't know, what I am doing wrong :(
Maybe some of you know that?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you explain your problem that you are facing and your requirement

Comment: Now, when my code is generated, I have something like this in the path to link in src code: <source src="s1">, and this is wrong. I need to have a path to file in this place, not the name of imported file. So, my code for dynamically create this path in map() function is wrong. I don't know what is wrong in this code and how it must be changed.

Comment: Why are you trying to use an `import` statement to retrieve the files? Instead you could output the path to the `src` attribute directly as follows: `src={\`./assets/sounds/s${i}.mp3\`}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the source as `./assets/sounds/s${i}.mp3` instead of `s${i}` and you will get the following `src="./assets/sounds/s1.mp3"`

EDIT for your specific case:

Put all the components into an array for example:

```
let soundPaths = [s1, s2, s3, s4 /*... and rest of components */]
```

Then in your `map()` function do

```
 <source src={soundPaths[i]} type="audio/mpeg"></source>
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but when I puted code like you wrote in my code: <source
                      src="/assets/sounds/s${1}.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></source>, after render this code looks the same - nothing changed. The path is not generated dynamically.

Comment: No no, put it with template literal and don't put ${1} but ${i}. And you forgot a dot.

Comment: I changed one thing - I used backticks and code is working :)

Comment: My code for path now looks like this: src={`./assets/sounds/s${i}.mp3`}

Comment: Yes, you need template literal (backticks) of course

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but still, something is wrong with this code. Now the generated code for path looks like this: <source src="./assets/sounds/s1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">. But when I put for path in src element name of the imported file, like this {s1}, then after rendering this code I have a path to mp3 file like this: '/static/media/s2.c23f59f8.mp3' and this code is working - after clicking element sound is playing. Code generated dynamically is not working :(

Comment: Ahhh now I get it! Your component has different path than from where its imported. Let me add something in EDIT.

Comment: We can see that if path is render from added file component, then some code is added to path, and this code is different for every path, e.g for component {s1} added code to path is: 'ea1c291b' and path looks like this: '/static/media/s1.ea1c291b.mp3', despite this that path in imported file is like this: "./assets/sounds/s1.mp3". I really don't understand this.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Can you please try it now?

Comment: Yes, this is working :) Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
import s0 from "./assets/sounds/s1.mp3";
import s1 from "./assets/sounds/s2.mp3";
import s2 from "./assets/sounds/s3.mp3";
import s3 from "./assets/sounds/s4.mp3";
import s4 from "./assets/sounds/s5.mp3";
import s5 from "./assets/sounds/s6.mp3";
import s6 from "./assets/sounds/s7.mp3";
import s7 from "./assets/sounds/s8.mp3";
import s8 from "./assets/sounds/s9.mp3";

sound=[
    {
       sound_name:"s1"
       path:s1
    },
    {
       sound_name:"s2"
       path:s2
    },    {
       sound_name:"s3"
       path:s3
    },    {
       sound_name:"s4"
       path:s4
    },    {
       sound_name:"s5"
       path:s5
    },    {
       sound_name:"s6"
       path:s6
    },    {
       sound_name:"s7"
       path:s7
    },    {
       sound_name:"s8"
       path:s8
    },
]
```

this is a way

```
   {soundsName.map((sound, i) => {
          return (
            <div
              className="drum-pad"
              onClick={this.soundPlay}
              title={"Sound " + sound.sound_name}
              key={i}
            >
              <audio className="clip" id={sound.sound_name}>
                <source src=sound.path type="audio/mpeg"></source>
              </audio>
              {sound.sound_name}
            </div>
          );
        })}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution, but when I used this I have this error: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {sound_name, path}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.